# Variadic template deduction in variadic template template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I am not sure if the title makes much sense, but the example is actually quite staightforward:

```
// A converter struct with a generic constructor.
template <template <typename ...> class TT>
struct converter
{
        template <typename ... Args>    
        converter(const TT<Args ...> &);
};

// A few class templates.
template <typename T>
struct foo {};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct foo2 {};

template <typename ... Args>
struct foo_variadic {};

template <typename Arg0, typename ... Args>
struct foo_variadic2 {};

int main()
{
        // All these compile.
        converter<foo>(foo<int>{});
        converter<foo2>(foo2<int,double>{});
        converter<foo_variadic>(foo_variadic<>{});   
        converter<foo_variadic>(foo_variadic<int>{});
        converter<foo_variadic>(foo_variadic<int,double>{});
        // This will not compile.
        // converter<foo_variadic2>(foo_variadic2<int>{});                     
}
```

I have tried with GCC 4.8.1 and clang 3.3, the error messages vary a bit but they all point to some problem deducing `Args` around line 5 (and subsequent exclusion of the `converter` constructor from the candidate list).

How is `foo_variadic2` special or different with respect to the other `foo`s?

(For the record, I am trying to implement an `is_instance_of` type trait to detect instances of template classes)

**UPDATE**

Now both GCC 4.8.3 and 4.9.1 on my setup accept this. clang 3.4.2 still barking.

Comment: With g++ it compiles fine, after changing one line 'converter(const TT<Args ...> &){}'

Comment: @DieterLücking Which version of GCC? (And did you uncomment the problematic line or did you accidentially compiled the code as posted?)

Comment: Not sure what's going on. [Here](http://ideone.com/I3is5s) is another case that I don't really understand. Oh, and for what it's worth, your example works in VS 2013 RC :P

Comment: @DanielFrey Oh, removing the comment it fails to compile

Comment: Your example works with GCC 4.9, though not with GCC 4.8 or clang 3.3.

Comment: @HighCommander4 thanks for checking this, gonna add an update to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the solution, but might help you or others to figure out what the problem is. The following compiles:

```
template <template <typename ...> class TT>
struct converter2
{
    template <typename Arg0, typename ... Args>    
    converter2(const TT<Arg0, Args ...> &);
};

// ...

converter2<foo_variadic2>(foo_variadic2<int>{});
```

I have to admit I don't understand why this is necessary and why your code doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! As you say it is not a general solution but a nice temporary workaround nevertheless.